# Apache StringSubstitutor - Replace not matching variables with empty string

Tags: java, apache-commons, string-substitution

**Precondition**

I have a string which looks like this:
`String myText= "This is a foo text containing ${firstParameter} and ${secondParameter}"`

And the code looks like this:

```
Map<String, Object> textParameters=new Hashmap<String,String>();
textParameters.put("firstParameter", "Hello World");
StringSubstitutor substitutor = new StringSubstitutor(textParameters);
String replacedText = substitutor.replace(myText)
```

The replacedText will be:
`This is a foo text containing Hello World and ${secondParameter}`

**The problem**

In the replaced string the `secondParameter` parameter was not provided so for this reason the declaration was printed out.

**What I want to achieve?**

If a parameter is not mapped then I want to hide its declaration by replacing it with an empty string.

In the example I want to achieve this:  `This is a foo text containing Hello World and`

**Question**

How can I achieve the mentioned result with StringUtils/Stringbuilder? Should I use regex instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by supplying your placeholder with a default value by appending `:-` to it. (For example `${secondParameter:-my default value}`).

In your case, you can also leave it empty to hide the placeholder if the key is not set.

```java
String myText = "This is a foo text containing ${firstParameter} and ${secondParameter:-}";
Map<String, Object> textParameters = new HashMap<>();
textParameters.put("firstParameter", "Hello World");
StringSubstitutor substitutor = new StringSubstitutor(textParameters);
String replacedText = substitutor.replace(myText);
System.out.println(replacedText);
// Prints "This is a foo text containing Hello World and "
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set default value for all variables, you can construct [`StringSubstitutor` with `StringLookup`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html#StringSubstitutor-org.apache.commons.text.lookup.StringLookup-), where the `StringLookup` just wrap the parameter map and use `getOrDefault` to provide your default value.

```java
import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;
import org.apache.commons.text.lookup.StringLookup;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SubstituteWithDefault {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myText = "This is a foo text containing ${firstParameter} and ${secondParameter}";
        Map<String, Object> textParameters = new HashMap<>();
        textParameters.put("firstParameter", "Hello World");
        StringSubstitutor substitutor = new StringSubstitutor(new StringLookup() {
            @Override
            public String lookup(String s) {
                return textParameters.getOrDefault(s, "").toString();
            }
        });
        String replacedText = substitutor.replace(myText);
        System.out.println(replacedText);
    }
}
```